# What is the reason of unstable perfomance when filling arrays and collections with primitive wrappers?

Tags: java, performance, jvm

Trying to understand the results of some simple tests. First the code with arrays:

```
public class TestFillingArrayOfIntegers {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] intArray = new Integer[20_000_000];

    fill(intArray);
    fill(intArray);
    fill(intArray);
    fill(intArray);
    fill(intArray);
  }

  static void fill(Integer[] in) {
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20_000_000; i++) { in[i] = i; }
    System.out.println((System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1_000_000 + " ms");
  }
}
```

It results in these numbers on my machine (Oracle Java 8 on Intel i5 desktop with Windows 10):

> ```
> 4442 ms
> 6634 ms
> 1038 ms
> 7745 ms
> 1210 ms
> ```

Now the code with ArrayList:

```
public class TestFillingArrayListOfIntegers {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.util.ArrayList<Integer> intList = new java.util.ArrayList<>();

    fill(intList);

    intList.clear();
    fill(intList);

    intList.clear();
    fill(intList);

    intList.clear();
    fill(intList);

    intList.clear();
    fill(intList);
  }

  static void fill(java.util.ArrayList<Integer> in) {
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20_000_000; i++) { in.add(i); }
    System.out.println((System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1_000_000 + " ms");
  }
}
```

Which results to

> ```
> 5155 ms
> 965 ms
> 7415 ms
> 93 ms
> 902 ms
> ```

I've tried Float also, with the same results. Numbers are almost the same from run to run.

Filling arrays of primitive types (i.e. int[]) is almost instant, always.

I just can't understand why the numbers gotten from serial method invocations are so different (here i don't ask about the performance issues with absolute values of these numbers). Have just one guess: filling arrays with wrappers uses all CPU cores of my machine, so may be the reason is in unstable multithreading.

And i know about flawed benchmarks and that using JMH is preferable. Just think my primitive tests are valid, please tell me if they are not.

Thanks.

=== [EDIT] added JMH tests ===

```
# JMH version: 1.19
# VM version: JDK 1.8.0_151, VM 25.151-b12
# VM invoker: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151\bin\java.exe
# VM options: <none>
# Warmup: 5 iterations, 1 s each
# Measurement: 5 iterations, 1 s each
# Timeout: 10 min per iteration
# Threads: 1 thread, will synchronize iterations
# Benchmark mode: Average time, time/op
# Benchmark: org.sample.MyBenchmark.testMethod
```

First the code for arrays:

```
package org.sample;

import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@Warmup(iterations = 5, time = 1, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 5, time = 1, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@Fork(3)
@State(Scope.Thread)
public class MyBenchmark {
  private Integer[] intArray;

  @Setup
  public void setup() {
    intArray = new Integer[20_000_000];
  }

  @Benchmark
  public void testMethod() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 20_000_000; i++) { intArray[i] = i; }
  }

}
```

And results:

```
# Run progress: 0,00% complete, ETA 00:00:30
# Fork: 1 of 3
# Warmup Iteration   1: 1607,614 ms/op
# Warmup Iteration   2: 7922,442 ms/op
# Warmup Iteration   3: 7430,643 ms/op
# Warmup Iteration   4: 1067,362 ms/op
# Warmup Iteration   5: 1257,112 ms/op
Iteration   1: 660,460 ms/op
Iteration   2: 1222,175 ms/op
Iteration   3: 664,795 ms/op
Iteration   4: 453,940 ms/op
Iteration   5: 460,370 ms/op

# Run progress: 33,33% complete, ETA 00:00:52
# Fork: 2 of 3
# Warmup Iteration   1: 1621,263 ms/op
# Warmup Iteration   2: 8021,981 ms/op
# Warmup Iteration   3: 7497,249 ms/op
# Warmup Iteration   4: 1052,803 ms/op
# Warmup Iteration   5: 1225,479 ms/op
Iteration   1: 642,912 ms/op
Iteration   2: 629,243 ms/op
Iteration   3: 644,419 ms/op
Iteration   4: 625,221 ms/op
Iteration   5: 449,515 ms/op

# Run progress: 66,67% complete, ETA 00:00:26
# Fork: 3 of 3
# Warmup Iteration   1: 1616,155 ms/op
# Warmup Iteration   2: 7972,240 ms/op
# Warmup Iteration   3: 7462,278 ms/op
# Warmup Iteration   4: 1039,186 ms/op
# Warmup Iteration   5: 1199,929 ms/op
Iteration   1: 635,411 ms/op
Iteration   2: 620,902 ms/op
Iteration   3: 635,565 ms/op
Iteration   4: 618,084 ms/op
Iteration   5: 443,779 ms/op


Result "org.sample.MyBenchmark.testMethod":
  627,119 ?(99.9%) 198,033 ms/op [Average]
  (min, avg, max) = (443,779, 627,119, 1222,175), stdev = 185,240
  CI (99.9%): [429,087, 825,152] (assumes normal distribution)


# Run complete. Total time: 00:01:19

Benchmark               Mode  Cnt    Score     Error  Units
MyBenchmark.testMethod  avgt   15  627,119 ? 198,033  ms/op
```

Seems results are not that stable, 1/3 for error is way too much. First run numbers are just awful.

Now the code for ArrayList:

```
package org.sample;

import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@Warmup(iterations = 5, time = 1, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 5, time = 1, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@Fork(3)
@State(Scope.Thread)
public class MyBenchmark {
  private java.util.ArrayList<Integer> intList;

  @Setup
  public void setup() {
    intList = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
  }

  @Benchmark
  public void testMethod() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 20_000_000; i++) { intList.add(i); }
  }

}
```

Result:

```
# Run progress: 0,00% complete, ETA 00:00:30
# Fork: 1 of 3
# Warmup Iteration   1: 6058,794 ms/op
# Warmup Iteration   2: 11194,466 ms/op
# Warmup Iteration   3: 1442,472 ms/op
# Warmup Iteration   4: 13665,291 ms/op
# Warmup Iteration   5: 1666,268 ms/op
Iteration   1: 3014,773 ms/op
Iteration   2: 3486,813 ms/op
Iteration   3: 41237,327 ms/op
Iteration   4: 1295,759 ms/op
Iteration   5: 28381,385 ms/op

# Run progress: 33,33% complete, ETA 00:04:17
# Fork: 2 of 3
# Warmup Iteration   1: 5965,381 ms/op
# Warmup Iteration   2: 11372,674 ms/op
# Warmup Iteration   3: 1483,890 ms/op
# Warmup Iteration   4: 13688,102 ms/op
# Warmup Iteration   5: 1699,179 ms/op
Iteration   1: 3055,685 ms/op
Iteration   2: 3433,376 ms/op
Iteration   3: 41953,165 ms/op
Iteration   4: 1316,909 ms/op
Iteration   5: 28855,626 ms/op

# Run progress: 66,67% complete, ETA 00:02:09
# Fork: 3 of 3
# Warmup Iteration   1: 6003,560 ms/op
# Warmup Iteration   2: 11353,880 ms/op
# Warmup Iteration   3: 1443,714 ms/op
# Warmup Iteration   4: 13688,473 ms/op
# Warmup Iteration   5: 2285,464 ms/op
Iteration   1: 3571,613 ms/op
Iteration   2: 4179,211 ms/op
Iteration   3: 41793,050 ms/op
Iteration   4: 1323,737 ms/op
Iteration   5: 28539,350 ms/op


Result "org.sample.MyBenchmark.testMethod":
  15695,852 ?(99.9%) 18165,612 ms/op [Average]
  (min, avg, max) = (1295,759, 15695,852, 41953,165), stdev = 16992,124
  CI (99.9%): [? 0, 33861,464] (assumes normal distribution)


# Run complete. Total time: 00:06:30

Benchmark               Mode  Cnt      Score       Error  Units
MyBenchmark.testMethod  avgt   15  15695,852 ? 18165,612  ms/op
```

ArrayList results are worse than these without JMH. The error deviation is bigger than result!

Any ideas?

Here are results with some non-default GC settings. I've tested arrays, just changed one string to "@Fork(value = 3, jvmArgsAppend = { "-Xms4096m", "-Xmx4096m", "-verbose:gc"})". Results:

```
# JMH version: 1.19
# VM version: JDK 1.8.0_151, VM 25.151-b12
# VM invoker: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151\bin\java.exe
# VM options: -Xms4096m -Xmx4096m -verbose:gc
# Warmup: 5 iterations, 1 s each
# Measurement: 5 iterations, 1 s each
# Timeout: 10 min per iteration
# Threads: 1 thread, will synchronize iterations
# Benchmark mode: Average time, time/op
# Benchmark: org.sample.MyBenchmark.testMethod

# Run progress: 0,00% complete, ETA 00:00:30
# Fork: 1 of 3
# Warmup Iteration   1: [GC (Allocation Failure)  1048576K->471308K(4019712K), 0.5042073 secs]
253,738 ms/op
# Warmup Iteration   2: [GC (Allocation Failure)  1519884K->767524K(4019712K), 0.5134485 secs]
[GC (Allocation Failure)  1816100K->1063700K(4019712K), 0.4944016 secs]
239,485 ms/op
# Warmup Iteration   3: [GC (Allocation Failure)  2112276K->1359908K(4019712K), 0.4932206 secs]
[GC (Allocation Failure)  2408484K->1656100K(4019712K), 0.4927346 secs]
212,527 ms/op
# Warmup Iteration   4: [GC (Allocation Failure)  2704676K->1952292K(3437056K), 0.4950558 secs]
[GC (Allocation Failure)  2418212K->2248136K(3728384K), 0.5216161 secs]
274,812 ms/op
# Warmup Iteration   5: [GC (Allocation Failure)  2714056K->2248120K(3728384K), 1.1181796 secs]
1193,570 ms/op
Iteration   1: [GC (Allocation Failure)  2714040K->2248136K(3728384K), 1.1205924 secs]
635,233 ms/op
Iteration   2: [GC (Allocation Failure)  2714056K->2248208K(3728384K), 1.1172824 secs]
1191,058 ms/op
Iteration   3: [GC (Allocation Failure)  2714128K->2248128K(3728384K), 1.1204173 secs]
634,724 ms/op
Iteration   4: [GC (Allocation Failure)  2714048K->2248168K(3728384K), 1.1276622 secs]
1204,162 ms/op
Iteration   5: [GC (Allocation Failure)  2714088K->2248208K(3728384K), 1.1234440 secs]
637,095 ms/op

# Run progress: 33,33% complete, ETA 00:00:26
# Fork: 2 of 3
# Warmup Iteration   1: [GC (Allocation Failure)  1048576K->471323K(4019712K), 0.5115167 secs]
252,752 ms/op
# Warmup Iteration   2: [GC (Allocation Failure)  1519899K->767531K(4019712K), 0.5080484 secs]
[GC (Allocation Failure)  1816107K->1063715K(4019712K), 0.4911580 secs]
238,002 ms/op
# Warmup Iteration   3: [GC (Allocation Failure)  2112291K->1359891K(4019712K), 0.4941844 secs]
[GC (Allocation Failure)  2408467K->1656083K(4019712K), 0.4919721 secs]
211,512 ms/op
# Warmup Iteration   4: [GC (Allocation Failure)  2704659K->1952275K(3437056K), 0.5040378 secs]
[GC (Allocation Failure)  2418195K->2248131K(3728384K), 0.5245958 secs]
276,411 ms/op
# Warmup Iteration   5: [GC (Allocation Failure)  2714051K->2248107K(3728384K), 1.1093389 secs]
1180,963 ms/op
Iteration   1: [GC (Allocation Failure)  2714027K->2248147K(3728384K), 1.1624603 secs]
652,570 ms/op
Iteration   2: [GC (Allocation Failure)  2714067K->2248155K(3728384K), 1.1054001 secs]
1177,282 ms/op
Iteration   3: [GC (Allocation Failure)  2714075K->2248147K(3728384K), 1.1469809 secs]
645,297 ms/op
Iteration   4: [GC (Allocation Failure)  2714067K->2248155K(3728384K), 1.1026592 secs]
1177,270 ms/op
Iteration   5: [GC (Allocation Failure)  2714075K->2248131K(3728384K), 1.1547916 secs]
651,064 ms/op

# Run progress: 66,67% complete, ETA 00:00:13
# Fork: 3 of 3
# Warmup Iteration   1: [GC (Allocation Failure)  1048576K->471299K(4019712K), 0.5202269 secs]
256,682 ms/op
# Warmup Iteration   2: [GC (Allocation Failure)  1519875K->767531K(4019712K), 0.5250656 secs]
[GC (Allocation Failure)  1816107K->1063731K(4019712K), 0.4992968 secs]
242,321 ms/op
# Warmup Iteration   3: [GC (Allocation Failure)  2112307K->1359939K(4019712K), 0.5023238 secs]
[GC (Allocation Failure)  2408515K->1656131K(4019712K), 0.5024830 secs]
215,224 ms/op
# Warmup Iteration   4: [GC (Allocation Failure)  2704707K->1952323K(3437056K), 0.5032048 secs]
[GC (Allocation Failure)  2418243K->2248127K(3728384K), 0.5347739 secs]
281,705 ms/op
# Warmup Iteration   5: [GC (Allocation Failure)  2714047K->2248167K(3728384K), 1.1136005 secs]
1188,756 ms/op
Iteration   1: [GC (Allocation Failure)  2714087K->2248143K(3728384K), 1.1517189 secs]
648,966 ms/op
Iteration   2: [GC (Allocation Failure)  2714063K->2248151K(3728384K), 1.1092591 secs]
1183,677 ms/op
Iteration   3: [GC (Allocation Failure)  2714071K->2248199K(3728384K), 1.1160382 secs]
631,461 ms/op
Iteration   4: [GC (Allocation Failure)  2714119K->2248207K(3728384K), 1.1566076 secs]
1238,393 ms/op
Iteration   5: [GC (Allocation Failure)  2714127K->2248215K(3728384K), 1.1143401 secs]
631,711 ms/op


Result "org.sample.MyBenchmark.testMethod":
  862,664 ?(99.9%) 301,000 ms/op [Average]
  (min, avg, max) = (631,461, 862,664, 1238,393), stdev = 281,556
  CI (99.9%): [561,664, 1163,665] (assumes normal distribution)


# Run complete. Total time: 00:00:40

Benchmark               Mode  Cnt    Score     Error  Units
MyBenchmark.testMethod  avgt   15  862,664 ? 301,000  ms/op
```

Can't see any help from this. No idea of all these "GC (Allocation Failure)". I've read about them but what is the reason of pauses? I gave 4GB of heap to JVM.

Comment: These  tests *definitely* aren't valid.  You're not taking JIT or any other optimizations into account, which is likely why you're getting sporadic results.  If you rerun your suite with JMH and still see these, then we may have something to really dig into.

Comment: I don't think the reason is in JIT warming. May be some (de)optimizations take place. Anyway, i'll try to make numbers with JMH, thanks.

Comment: Are you confused between the difference in timing between these two tests? Or between these two tests and an equivalent test using a primitive array?

Comment: I don't get why subsequent runs of the same method give so different results. I don't ask here why one way of storing and filling data is faster.

Comment: Try initializing the `ArrayList` with an initial capacity of 20M.

Comment: ArrayList is initiated already in @Setup section.

Comment: `new java.util.ArrayList<>(20_000_000);`

Comment: Done. Score 5843,947, Error  8639,148 ms/op. Wall times became smaller, but error deviation even bigger.

Comment: Yes.  That will help.  But you still have the overhead of create 20 new million wrapper objects for each `fill` test cycle.  If you want to eliminate that, then create a single wrapper object and fill all 20 million cells with that.  The performance will be competitive with an array ... and not lumpy.

Comment: I see. But here my goal is to understand the inner reasons of deviations. The code is pretty basic, it can be met in real life, and that it is. May be disassembly can show the reason, but a don't know how to read it.

Comment: Filling an array is a rather fast operation. Multi-second pauses are obviously caused by GC. Run the test with a constant size heap (-Xmx = -Xms) and with GC logs on (-verbose:gc).

Comment: I've added some testing with non-default GC settings. Can you please comment?

Comment: The logs prove that you have GC pauses more than 1 sec long while each iteration of microbenchmark is supposed to last for 1 sec at most. This makes benchmark scores meaningless.

Comment: Basically @IdrisKubataev  ... you need to stop *disbelieving* what lots of experienced Java programmers are telling you.

Comment: @apangin I've changed iterations to run for 10 seconds. Timings are more accurate, but error is still 1/6 of result time. Is it OK? Changing array to 1 kk elements definitely solve the problem, but is it possible to have stable results for 20 kk elements tuning GC settings?

Comment: @StephenC I'll appreciate your help finding the answer to my questions. Just saying "it's GC" in not an answer. I still want to know is it OK to make unpredictable GC pauses and is it possible to get rid of them tuning GC.

Comment: Why are you not satisfied with results? What do you want to measure? If you want to exclude GC overhead from measurements, set 100GB heap to avoid GC at all. If you want to count amortized GC costs, run the test for an hour.

Comment: @apangin Seems it is not possible to work with 20M arrays without GC pauses. Seems that is the answer to the question.

Comment: @IdrisKubataev - Unfortunately, it took you a very long time to ask your actual question.  Zero pause collection and benchmark stability are NOT the same thing.

Comment: @IdrisKubataev: this is not about the 20M *array*. It’s about creating and dropping 20M temporary objects while always having 20M survivor objects. A real life application rarely overwrites an array multiple times with new objects without doing anything useful with these objects. But if that’s really your issue, try running the JVM with `-Xms4G -Djava.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high=20000000` and watch the difference…

Comment: @Holger -Djava.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high=20000000 -Xmn600m made results fast and stable. It takes some time for JVM to start with that cache. Running JVM with -Xms14g -Xmx14g also gives stable results, but no so fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple likely sources of "instability" in this example:

1. JIT compilation overheads
2. Heap warm-up as the heap increases to the size required by your workingset, and deals with garbage created during class loading and JIT compilation
3. Garbage collection necessitated by your application's memory churn.

One reason that you get different behavior for an list of wrappers versus an array of primitives is that creating each wrapper instance is going to allocate a new object on the heap.  In the primitive case, there are no wrapper objects to allocate.

> And i know about flawed benchmarks and that using JMH is preferable. Just think my primitive tests are valid, please tell me if they are not.

They are not valid for the reasons (points 1 & 2) above.

Note however, that "eliminating" the GC overheads (point 3 above) from the measurements would distort the results.  The GC overheads should be considered as part of the overall costs when comparing arrays and lists.

Use JMH.

---

This seems to be the nub of your question:

> *"I still want to know is it OK to make unpredictable GC pauses"*

GC pauses **are** effectively unpredictable, if that is what is what you mean.

If you try hard enough and know enough about what your application is doing, the current heap size, the GC parameters, etc, you can make an educated guess as to when they will happen<sup>1</sup>.  But it is not practical to make such predictions *a priori*.  There are too many variables.

> *" ... and is it possible to get rid of them tuning GC"*.

There is no way to entirely eliminate GC pauses by tuning<sup>2</sup>. You can *reduce their length* (using a low-pause collector) but not eliminate them.  And reduction comes at a cost of the JVM spending more time *overall* on garbage collection and related overheads.

They are a fact of life.

> *"Seems it is not possible to work with 20M arrays without GC pauses."*

Correct.  Unless ... you can design your application so that it doesn't allocate any new objects after it has started up<sup>3</sup>.

---

<sup>1 - For example, in your benchmark the code is simple enough that the behavior is reproducible.</sup>

<sup>2 - Even with low-pause collectors such as CMS and G1, a "new space" collection will pause all non-GC threads.  The pause is relatively short ... provided that you don't make the "new" space too large.  But you cannot eliminate it.</sup>

<sup>3 - In theory, an application that allocates no objects during normal operation should generate no garbage, and hence have no GC pauses ... after the JVM has warmed up.  But to achieve this, you need write your application to avoid using most many / most standard Java SE classes.  Very difficult.</sup>

Comment: I am aware of 1, 2 and 3. The same time can't understand how can they explain these numbers: 4442, 6634 (~1,5 times up), 1038 (~6 times down), 7745 (~7 times up), 1210 (~7 times down).
Anyway, i've made JMH tests, but they don't make situation any clearer.

Comment: I think that they do explain it.  The GC and the JIT compiler are kicking in at certain points ... making elapsed times longer.  Re JMH - see my *"One reason that you get different behavior ..."*.  Even with JMH tests, you are measuring those overheads.  If you want JMH numbers with small error bars, you will need to run the rests for a **long time** to smooth out the "lumpyness" caused by memory churn + GC.

Comment: @IdrisKubataev: you are creating 19999982 objects in each operation and do not believe that there could be garbage collection happening in some of them?

Comment: @Holger Not really. The case is that I see no connection of pauses and subsequent runs. And why does GC make these pauses at all, given plenty of memory. Please see latest addition to the post.

Comment: @IdrisKubataev: what does `time = 1, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS` mean? I suppose, to run for one second in each iteration. Allocating 20M `Integer`s (32b each) requires 640MiB, the gc logs says you have a young generation of ~2700000K at the end, which is full after four iterations. Now, the smallest execution time reported says “212ms/op” which makes it reasonable to assume that four repetitions in a second *are* possible, so a gc always occurs when running for a second, but takes a second on its own. Now consider, gc may happen before the first or after the fourth repetition in that second…

Comment: @Holger I take your reasons, but i'd like to have more convincing proof. Here in Chrome i can see when GC pauses happen and how long. Is it possible to visualize these pauses in Java?

Comment: @IdrisKubataev: just to ensure that I got you correctly… your JVM log does already tell you when a gc happened, how long it took and how many bytes it reclaimed, but you are not convinced because it doesn’t “visualize” it?

Comment: @Holger OK. What can i see from the sting "Warmup Iteration   1: [GC (Allocation Failure)  1048576K->471323K(4019712K)"? First, logically broken message "GC (Allocation Failure)" as there is no failure at all, i't just how GC authors decide to write some things. Second, "1048576K->471323K(4019712K)" - what is it? It is memory GC used before compaction, after compaction and total JVM memory. What useful info do these numbers give? Third, these logs say nothing about the moment GC compaction activated. Was it before iteration, after or in the process? No info. And yes, i'll prefer visualization.

Comment: @StephenC I'd like to select your answer as final, but please add some notes about amount of memory JVM has to work with before GC happens. The case is that running my very first programs with large memory flags (-Xms and -Xmx with 8g or 16g) result in fast and stable results without any JMH. Nobody advised me to use them. it's a pity really.

Comment: @Idris Kubataev if you want to see the garbage collection happening, have you tried using visualvm? It's a tool that lets you see heap size and GC activity. A version of it comes included in the jdk called jvisualvm.exe

Comment: @Alan Thank you for the tip. I'll try to use visualvm next time.

Comment: Re: initial heap sizes, it turns out that setting a large "initial" size is not sufficient to ensure that you won't get an early GC.  The first GC will be triggered when the "new space" gets full.  Like I said it is difficult to predict when the GC is going to run.

Comment: Re: stability.  As I tried to point out, you should not be aiming for stable performance numbers in this benchmark.  If you manage to get stable performance numbers with these benchmarks, then they are not realistic.  You should be including the GC overheads when you compare the performance of array of primitive versus ArrayList.

Comment: One more note. I've tried latest Java 9.0.1 and got interesting results. Java 9 with default settings provide WAY faster and stable speeds, but use ~1,5 times more RAM for working set and ~2-3 times more virtual memory for commit.